# Writing new code in async but calling sync

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous-programming, technical-debt

I am writing some new code and would like to write it using async and await, but the calling code does not currently support async. Is it right to write the new code in async and call it sync until the calling code supports async?

Or should I write the code sync and then convert it at a later date? And would it be considered technical debt?

```
public Result Execute( Paramerters parameters ) {
    return ExecuteAsync( parameters ).Result;
}

public Task<Result> ExecuteAsync( Paramerters parameters ) {
    ...
}
```

`Execute` is on an interface and is called from some other code that is not yet async. Is it correct to create the async version and call it from `Execute` until the code calling `Execute` is converted to async?
My old code is written in .net 4.5.1 but is not yet converted to async.

Comment: What do you mean by "calling code"? Could you show us some code that represents your problem?

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic I have updated my question

Comment: your sample doesn't include the `async` and `await` keywords.  I'm not sure what you're trying to acomplish

Comment: @MetaFight The code that is in ExecuteAsync would be async and await code like db access, web requests but that doesnt matter THe question is should I write it using async then call it from the sync method or write the code all sync then convert it at a later time

Comment: you may want to look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods? by Stephen Toub

Answer (score 3):

If you want to call asynchronous code synchronously, you need to handle the synchronization. Only idea I have is that you would block the calling thread till the asynchronous operation finishes. I would consider that extremely dangerous, because it might lead to deadlocks. Especially if you are working in UI, where Tasks are scheduled to run on the UI thread and you would be blocking that exact thread. Example here : [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

So I'm for writing synchronous code until you are able to change the caller to asynchronous version.

Answer (score 0):

In any case there is a technical debt, but we must do to lighten the best. 
better change immediately to async and await

Your code will be somme thing ike this :

```
public Result Execute(string parameters)
{
    Task<Result> task = Task.Run<Result>(async () => await ExecuteAsync());
    return task.Result;
}

public async Task<Result> ExecuteAsync(string parameters)
{
    Task<Result> result = SomeOtherOperationAsync();
    // more code here...
    return await result;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: do not vote down very quickly. be patient communicate and ask questions.

Comment: Downvotes are reversible.

Comment: ok good, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to make the code asynchronous? If it's because the design requires support for asynchronous calls, then write it using `async`/`await`. If there's no requirement for the code to be asynchronous, then don't. If requirements change later and require the code to be refactored, then it's not technical debt, it's just adapting to changing requirements. OTOH, if you write it as async and incur overhead to call it synchronously, then that's bad design. Likewise, making code harder to debug and reason about for no reason is also bad design. So unless it's clear your path forward is async, keep it synchronous.